# Why does curl sftp fail with curl: (2) Failure establishing ssh session

Tags: raspberry-pi, curl, sftp

This on a Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1 Running Jessie.

I am trying to eliminate all my .netrc files and set up all file transfers to my web host using public key authentication.

It works for ssh:

```
pi@rasp ~/.ssh $ ssh myname@mydomain.com
Last login: Sun Aug  8 17:44:47 2021 from node-p2s.pool-101-51.dynamic.totinternet.net
myname@mydomain.com [~]# exit
```

It works for plain old sftp:

```
pi@rasp ~/.ssh $ sftp myname@ftp.mydomain.com
Connected to ftp.mydomain.com.
sftp>
```

It works for scp:

```
pi@rasp ~/webcam $ scp rasp.txt myname@mydomain.com:~/public_html
rasp.txt                                      100%   16     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

But it fails for curl/sftp:

```
pi@rasp ~/webcam $ curl -v -T rasp.txt -u \
myname: --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
sftp://ftp.mydomain.com/~/public_html/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
*   Trying 192.254.225.101...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connected to ftp.mydomain.com (192.254.225.101) port 22 (#0)
* Failure establishing ssh session
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (2) Failure establishing ssh session
```

Note that it works fine on my Pi 4's running Buster. So, I'm assuming it must be something to do with either Jessie or the version of curl that I'm running on it:

```
pi@rasp ~/webcam $ curl -V
curl 7.38.0 (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

It advertises itself as supporting sftp, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I see in your username `myname:` (with colon on the end). Maybe it need to be `myname`?

Comment: No, it needs that colon. Here it is on a Pi 4 running Buster: 

pi@raspsky:~/webcam $ /usr/bin/curl -T test.txt -u myname: --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $host -- works just fine.

Comment: You specified a public key file with `curl`, but not `ssh` and `scp`. Is it possible `ssh` and `scp` used a different public key than you specified with `curl`?

Comment: Interesting question, but the only public key that account has is id_rsa.pub.